# fetch row id from oracle using Java

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, oracle11g, oracle10g

I need to fetch rowid from Oracle database using Java. I have used the below code.

```
Statement st = con.createStatement();
ResultSet rs=st.executeQuery("select * from ABC");
while(rs.next()) {
            RowId str=rs.getRowId(1);        
            System.out.println(str);
        }
```

The result I am getting is

```
oracle.sql.ROWID@2ce6c6ec
oracle.sql.ROWID@1bae316d
```

but I need hexadecimal values like

```
AAAdItACwAABXcIAAA
```

Can anyone guide me on this?

thanks

Comment: You are probably using an outdated JDBC driver, because newer drivers properly implement `ROWID.toString()`

Comment: As you can see [in the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/RowId.html) - **toString() returns the contents of its ROWID in a form specific to the driver supplying the connection, and possibly not as a ROWID literal**.
What you actually want to get? If you try to load ID column - just get in by column name

Comment: Try this and see if it prints what you want `System.out.println(new String(rowId.getBytes()));`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name could you please let me know the correct driver for this. which version i may use.

Comment: @PushpeshKumarRajwanshi thanks ..this seems to be working and i am able to fetch the values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/DatatypeConverter.html#printHexBinary%28byte%5B%5D%29

This will directly provide you the hexadecimal value

```
String hexValue = DatatypeConverter.printHexBinary(resultSet.getRowId(10).getBytes())
```

Here is the full code

```
Statement st = con.createStatement();
ResultSet rs=st.executeQuery("select * from ABC");
while(rs.next()) 
{
    String str= DatatypeConverter.printHexBinary(resultSet.getRowId(1).getBytes())       
    System.out.println(str);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From the Java Docs

> Retrieving RowId Objects Retrieve a java.sql.RowId object by calling
>   the getter methods defined in the interfaces ResultSet and
>   CallableStatement. The RowId object that is returned is an immutable
>   object that you can use for subsequent referrals as a unique
>   identifier to a row. The following is an example of calling the
>   ResultSet.getRowId method:

```
java.sql.RowId rowId_1 = rs.getRowId(1);
```

String  toString()
Returns a String representing the value of the SQL ROWID designated by this java.sql.RowId object.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/class-use/RowId.html